# Can't set video quality

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization V, I want to raise the quality of the "Leader scenes" in the video options box.  The "Minimum" setting is simply a still picture.  Why are the "Low" and "Medium" settings grayed out, leaving only "Minimum?"  For that matter, why are there no "High" and/or "Maximum" settings?

Comment: Usually this is a result of hardware limitations. The game detects your hardware and makes higher settings unavailable because of performance reasons.